# Recursively add a node at a certain index on Linked List

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to add a list node at a specified index recursively. By that I mean the List class addAtRec() calls addAtRec() in the ListNode class, that method is supposed to be recursive.

This is what I did:

List:

```
public class List implements Cloneable {

private ListNode firstNode;
private ListNode lastNode;
private String name;
private int counter;

public List(){
    this("list");
}
public void addAtRec(Object obj, int k)
{
    if(firstNode != null)
        firstNode.addAtRec(obj, k, firstNode);
}
}
```

That's of course only the relevant parts...

ListNode:

```
public class ListNode implements Cloneable {

Object data;
ListNode nextNode;
public ListNode(Object o){
    this(o,null);
}
public ListNode(Object o,ListNode node){
    data=o;
    nextNode=node;
}
public void addAtRec(Object obj, int k, ListNode current) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(current.nextNode == null && k != 0)
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(); //line 47
    if(k == 0)
    {
        ListNode l = new ListNode(obj);
        l.nextNode = current.nextNode;
        current.nextNode = l;
    }
    current = current.nextNode;
    addAtRec(obj, k, current); //line 55
    k--;
}
```

ListIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public class ListIndexOutOfBoundsException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

my main() method:

```
String s1 = "Objects";
    String s2 = "to";
    String s3 = "check";
    String s4 = "are";
    String s5 = "strings";
    List list = new List("My list");
    list.insertAtBack(s1);
    list.insertAtBack(s2);
    list.insertAtBack(s3);
    list.insertAtBack(s4);
    list.insertAtBack(s5);

    list.addAtRec(s3, 2);
```

and the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
at ListNode.addAtRec(ListNode.java:47)
at ListNode.addAtRec(ListNode.java:55)
at ListNode.addAtRec(ListNode.java:55)
at ListNode.addAtRec(ListNode.java:55)
at ListNode.addAtRec(ListNode.java:55)
at List.addAtRec(List.java:158)
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Well, you could show us how `insertAtBack` method looks like

Comment: @darijan that method is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your recursive method:

1. Before calling `addAtRec(obj, k, current);` you should decrease `k` by 1, so it would be better to call `k--` before this line.
2. Once you have reached the base case (when `k == 0`)and executed the logic to add the new node, your recursive method must stop, probably with a simple `return;` statement. In this case, you're not stopping it so you will call it every time until get to the end of your list.

Based on these 2 advices, your code should look like:

```
public void addAtRec(Object obj, int k, ListNode current)
    throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    //always use braces even for single line block of code
    if(current.nextNode == null && k != 0) {
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if(k == 0) {
        ListNode l = new ListNode(obj);
        l.nextNode = current.nextNode;
        current.nextNode = l;
        //stopping the recursion
        return;
    }
    current = current.nextNode;
    //decrease k by 1 before calling your method recursively
    k--;
    addAtRec(obj, k, current);
}
```

This is not part of the main problem, but IMO your methods to add nodes in the list should belong to the `List` class and not to the`ListNode`. Remember that the data structure that holds the nodes and decide how to tie them will be the `List`, not the nodes by themselves.