# Off by one linked list recursive insert with index

Tags: java, recursion, head

I am having trouble understanding how to deal with this off by one. Because if I decrease by one before the call I get a negative, which ruins everything. Static tail is not allowed, so do I need to create a previous Node each time?

```
       public void recInsert(Object o, int index){

    //No invalid inputs
    if(index < 0){
        throw new RuntimeException("Clearly out of bounds");
    }
    if(isEmpty() && index != 0){
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't insert there on empty list");
    }
    recInsertHelper(index, o, head);

}

private void recInsertHelper(int index, Object o, Node current){

    if(current == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("too big");
    }
    if(index == 0){
        current.next = new Node(o, current.next);
    } else {
        recInsertHelper(index-1, o, current.next);
    }

}
```

I even tried changing base case to the answer @ [Recursively add a node at a certain index on Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261687/recursively-add-a-node-at-a-certain-index-on-linked-listg)

acer + R, 0 =
aRcer Should be Racer

Updated Code:

```
public void recInsert(Object o, int index){
        //No invalid inputs
        if(index < 0){
            throw new RuntimeException("Clearly out of bounds");
        }
        if(isEmpty() && index != 0){
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't insert there on empty list");
        }
        if(!isEmpty() && index == 0){
            head = new Node(o, head);
        } else {
            recInsertHelper(index - 1, o, head);
        }
    }

    private void recInsertHelper(int index, Object o, Node current){

        if(current == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("too big");
        }
        if(index == 0){
            current.next = new Node(o, current.next);
        } else {
            recInsertHelper(index - 1, o, current.next);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just a tip, you should throw a more descriptive exception than `RuntimeException`. Such as `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What do you mean, off by one?

Comment: It is one to the right where it should not be. So instead of 0 index it is going into 1 index. Yeah I am working on it now, sorry for omission of the -- or -1.

Comment: Well, if you set `current.next` to the new node, where else would you expect the node to be inserted?

Comment: Well I tried the code on the only question I found similar to mine:

            Node temp = new Node(o);
            temp.next = current.next;
            current.next = temp;
            return;

Comment: That also doesn't work because you're working with a temporary reference that will fall out of scope as soon as you exit the method.

Comment: Have you considered setting `current.prev` instead? With the proper update to `head` if needed?

Comment: Theres no way just adjust the head? I can't use instance variables. Only the head

Comment: Wait, you can't change the head? Am I reading your comment correctly?

Comment: I can adjust the head. I just don't have a previous/tail function.

Comment: Oh, so you have a singly-linked list. Have you considered a special case where `index == 0` *before* recursing into the list?

Comment: Great , I guess I couldn't get it as short as I had hoped. 
Will have to memorize it all for the midterm tomorrow. Thank you, post an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: No problem! I'll have one up in a bit, with some extra info.

Comment: Never mind, my brain was fried...

Comment: Hmmm, did your `Node` class lose a constructor? Your 1-line insert suddenly became 3 lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, for a singly-linked list, insertion at an index works slightly differently than you're expecting. AS you can only insert forwards, insertions for a singly-linked list are a place *ahead* of where you would expect; as a result, you'll have to do an explicit check for if `index` is 0. Long story short, `index` is the node you're going to insert in front of.

So you'll need to do something like this in `recInsert()`:

```
if (index == 0) {
    // insert new node at head
else {
    // Not inserting at head, so subtract 1 for "passing" head and continue
    recInsertHelper(index - 1, o, head);
}
```

And I believe your `recInsertHelper()` can stay the same, as you compensated for the offset in `recInsert()`.